# Using Python Shell (Idle or Idle 3) I get Run time error and suggestion that I "Try running from Root"

Tags: python

Main problem is that when I want to run Python (.py) programs, I get error **saying I need to run from the "root".** I thought this meant I needed to have my python program in the folder "root".  In the Python shell, I am denied access to the "root" folder.

BackGround :  New to the Raspberry Pi.   I received a new RPi, along with noobie software. I intend to use Python to do most programming.  I allowed Raspian and Python to install. During setup I told system to Not boot into GUI (just to be safe).

My program (test.py) **will run from the Linux prompt** (Outside of the GUI).  At bootup, I change the directory to where my file is (cd  Marla_Folder).  I then type "sudo python test.py". I don't yet know why I need "sudo", but from researching, I discovered that this works.

I now want to work within in the GUI since I can see that the GUI will be easier to work within.

I start the GUI using "startx" and all is well.

Using **LXTerminal in my directory,  all works well** if I type "sudo python test.py.  Program runs.

When I use the "IDLE" or "IDLE3" (Python Shell), I open my file (test.py). Another window opens and I can see my program.  I then use pull down menu RUN.  And I select "RUN MODULE".   I get error :  Run time error . . . import RPI.GPIO as RPIO . . . no access to /dev/mem"  and message saying "Try running as Root"

It seems to me that I have my file in a folder that can't be run from the "root"  By the way, I am familiar with old DOS (but not Linux), thus my feeling I have a wrong folder.

QUESTION :     I want to use the "Idle" and "Idle3" (Python shells ). I like the way commands are colored to make recognition better.  I get error and message telling me to "try running from the root.  How can I run from the root when using Idle and Idle3 ?
I have tried searching the site here with lots of keywords, and have been unsucsessful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As answered earlier the problem is with needing root privileges to access /dev/mem.  Programs which manipulate the gpios need to use /dev/mem as the gpios are memory mapped.  The RPi and RPIO Python packages access /dev/mem and require root privileges to run.

The [pigpio](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html) Python module works differently.  It does not require you to use root privileges to run Python.  It communicates with a separate daemon process which may be loaded at system start-up.  The daemon alone needs to be run with /dev/mem privileges.

Comment: thank you for the link to pigpio. Question : After login (at the Linux prompt, can I simply type "sudo pigpio" to install? I don't want to make a non-reversable error (still stumbling with Linux understanding.

Comment: Once the library has been built and installed (make/make install) the daemon can be started by sudo pigpiod.  The daemon will then remain in memory until killed (sudo killall pigpiod) or the system is rebooted.

Answer (score 2):

Obvious (but wrong on so many levels) solution would be run `IDLE` as root using `sudo` command. this might work, but it's very dangerous from the security standpoint.

A better solution would be to open your python files in `IDLE` to edit, and open another terminal window on the desktop, where you may type `sudo python yourscripy.py` and have it run with escalated privileges.

You don't need access to `/root` folder to do anything from above, folder `/root` is not supposed to be used for everyday purpose.

Comment: thank you lenik. I have been opening another terminal and running the files. That was how I had verified that my code worked.  I guess I was just being typical lazy when I saw the one click "RUN MODULE" button in IDLE. All comments and Answers have helped me to move forward.

Comment: glad to help =)

Answer (score 1):

Unless you post your Python program there is no way of determining exactly what your problem is.

I assume you are trying to access the GPIO via the /dev memory mapping, and for this you need `root` permission (this is what `sudo` does at the terminal).

There are many ways around this e.g. setting `suid` permission on the memory mapped devices or using the `WiringPi` http://wiringpi.com/ `gpio` utility.

Comment: his/her problem is accessing `/dev/mem` through GPIO package without enough privileges as the error message clearly says, why do you need any source code to figure this out?

Comment: @lenik I guessed this - as you would see from my reply. This does not however enable you to make any constructive suggestions to help the questioner.